# Should I use two tables or role system for admins and users in laravel POS system?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and I am confusing that should i use two tables or role system for admins and users in laravel POS system. I want to know to is that which method will be more suitable for POS and why.

Comment: Thats upto you how you wants to manage

Comment: My recomendation is: Use what Laravel gives you, it makes things easier most of the time